# What are the key chemical characteristics that determine the octane rating of fuel?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, combustion, fuel, petrochemistry

The [octane rating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_rating) of petrol (gasoline) is a measure of the how much compression a fuel air mixture can have before detonating (which in petrol engines is a bad thing as you want the mix to combust only when the spark plug arcs).

What are the key chemical characteristics that determine this rating? What is the molecular-level explanation? And how do the various non-hydrocarbon additives work to modify the result?

Answer (score 8):

Combustion
 is (usually) chain radical reaction with heavy branching. More 
branching means faster combustion and less branching is slower 
combustion. And detonation is wave of super-fast combustion.

So, if you can suppress branching or deaden some branches, you can 
increase durability of air-fuel mixture. Actually, this means, that some
 radical trap is needed. The oldest trap was tetraethyllead, but it is 
currently dropped (lead oxides as fine dust is not a health friendly 
substance). Non-saturated hydrocarbons of different types also can trap 
active radicals, transforming them into more stable allyl radicals, so 
fuel companies tries to keep as much of them in fuel as possible. Some 
other compounds, like ferrocene, also can be used to increase octane 
rating.

Comment: What do you mean by branching and suppressing branching?

Comment: @BenNorris: When people talk about radical-based reactions, often three types of step are referred to: initiation, a reaction which makes a radical; propagation, a reaction which preserves the number of radical species, and termination, a reaction which consumes a radical. But, if you have a reaction which produces more radicals than it consumes, you get 'branching', which accelerates the rate of the overall reaction since now more propagation and termination steps can happen.

Comment: Ah, okay. Since the question was about octane rating, I, as an organic chemist, was trying to relate this answer to branched molecules, for example [isooctane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isooctane) (defined octane rating of 100) is a more branched structure than [heptane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptane) (which is defined as octane rating of 0).

Comment: @BenNorris Branched hydrocarbons usually have higher octane rating as they can product tertiary radical: most stable of alkyl radicals.