# Why do branched hydrocarbons burn more efficiently (complete & clean combustion)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, combustion, fuel

Branched and cycled hydrocarbons usually a higher octane number than their straight chain counterparts. This is due to a more complete and clean (no residue) combustion. In addition, there is no probability of knocking or detonation.

What are the reasons behind this?

Comment: Possible answer in permeakra's final comment to his [answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2454/what-are-the-key-chemical-characteristics-that-determine-the-octane-rating-of-fu/2455#2455) to [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2454/what-are-the-key-chemical-characteristics-that-determine-the-octane-rating-of-fu).

Comment: @hb2py I was just about to respond with that as an answer. That is almost certainly the correct explanation.